# StandardDeviation: Bias corrected or not?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, implementation-details

just a short question to my understanding it regards to

```
StandardDeviation[list]
```

StandardDevation is the square root of

```
Variance[list]
```

and i am sure it is implemented that way.

So the question is: Does Mathematica use the bias-corrected (unbiased) calculation with $\frac{1}{n-1}$ or the biased one with $\frac{1}{n}$ ?

Thanks

Comment: @wolfies ...taken care of by edit since it seems to have been a simple mistake of OP.

Answer (score 10):

According to the docs for [`StandardDeviation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardDeviation.html),

```
StandardDeviation[list]
```

uses the "sample standard deviation", i.e. the one with `1/(n-1)`. For a distribution `dist` based on a finite population of size `n` (with equal weights), however, it would use `1/n`.

Sample standard deviation:

```
StandardDeviation[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
(*  Sqrt[5/3]  *)
```

If a list is a complete population and not a sample, one can use [`EmpiricalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html) to get the other one.

```
StandardDeviation@EmpiricalDistribution[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
(*  Sqrt[5]/2  *)
```

...Or multiply by `Sqrt[(n-1)/n]`....

Comment: I don't see how the calculation involves `n` when applied to a distribution.

Comment: @mikado It's a for a ***population*** (as opposed to a sample) of finite size $n$. Or do you mean `Sqrt[5]/2 == Sqrt[5]/Sqrt[4]`, since the size `n` for `{1, 2, 3, 4}` is `4`?

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Yes that makes sense to differ between the sample list [LIST] (comming for a probe) which has to divided by 1/(n-1) ; this is the common thougts in the literature and the FULL distribution [dist] which uses 1/n

Comment: @mikado For some reason, I didn't see the ambiguity you were referring to at first. (I thought you meant the last example.) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MelaniePatriciaGerber wrote:  `FULL distribution [dist] which uses 1/n ` ... A _distribution_ does not have a size $n$. A distribution is a theoretical construct. Perhaps you are referring to the distinction between a population of size _N_, and a sample of size _n_.

Comment: @wolfies That's partly my fault, because I originally misused the term, too. I couldn't find a command to calculate the population s.d. in *M* without converting it into a distribution. And then I didn't quite get across what I meant when I used "distribution" for `EmpiricalDistribution[list]`, which does have a size `n` associated with it.

Comment: Hi Michael ... yes ... it can be a bit confusing because mma uses the same function name `Variance` to handle both the theoretical distribution and sample data.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Details section of [documentation for `Variance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variance.html):

> `Variance[list]` is equivalent to `Total[(list-Mean[list])^2]/(Length[list]-1)` for real-valued data.

So it uses the calculation with 1/(n-1).